# Using REGEX over split string

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, split

I'm trying to split a string into sub string, splitting by the 'AND' term, and after that
clean each sub string from "garbage".

The following code get the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

```
import re
def fun(self, str):
    for subStr in str.split('AND'):
        p = re.compile('[^"()]+')
        m = p.match(subStr)
        print (m.group())
```

Comment: What is the value of `str`?

Comment: That's what happens when there is no match... you have to check whether `m` contains any elements before trying to `group` them.

Comment: using try and except ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the `match` is not found, and it returned `None`.

Note that you might want to use `re.search` here instead of `re.match`. `re.match` matches only at the beginning of the string while `re.search` can search anywhere in the string.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the **beginning of**
>   the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

If you already know that then you can handle that `None` using:

```
if m:
   print (m.group())
else:
   #do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code above is what you really want to do, wouldn't it be easier to remove the garbage first using string.translate. Something like:

```
import string

def clean_and_split(x):
   return string.translate(x, None, r'^"()').split("AND")
```